# Is it weird for an undergrad or grad quant/applied maths(/even pure maths) programme to not teach that probabilities of 0 or 1 will never change?

Tags: undergraduate-education, graduate-education, statistics, probability

**Edit**: i didn't mean it like this programme should do this or that. i mean other people are accusing me like 'your programme should've had this or that' (actually they're saying that i should know this or that *anyway* given what my programme taught me, but let's just pretend it's the accusations i sound outside these round brackets). so my hope is that it's not weird at all so i can defeat them in the argument.

---

Of course we knew what Bayes' theorem was and we have all the tools to answer this at either basic or advanced level, but we never learned explicitly  the following (and consequently anything about prior and posterior probability except for what I [had to self-study for a make-up project](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173056/how-exactly-do-bayesians-define-or-interpret-probability) but even then I didn't yet know the ff)

> [no probability that is 0 or 1 should ever change.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192179/why-does-a-probability-of-0-or-1-remain-unchanged-with-new-information-intuitiv)

## **Basic**:

> Let $(\Omega, \text{sigma-algebras don't exist}, \mathbb P)$ be a
> probability space.
>
> Let $A,B$ be events with $B$ non-zero probability. Then:
>
> $P(A|B)=1$ if $P(A)=1$.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186619/does-an-unconditional-probability-of-1-or-0-imply-a-conditional-probability-of-1

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494682/is-it-correct-to-say-that-pa-1-to-pab-1-pa-1-to-pab-pa

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515756/is-a-probability-of-0-or-1-given-information-up-to-time-t-unchanged-by-informati

## **Advanced**:

> Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \{\mathscr{F}_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, \mathbb{P})$, let $A \in \mathscr{F}$.
>
> Suppose $$\exists t \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{s.t.} \ E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = 1 \ \text{a.s.}$$ Does it follow that $$E[1_A | \mathscr{F_{s}}] = E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] \ \text{a.s.} \ \forall s > t \ ?$$ What about $\forall s < t$?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192179/why-does-a-probability-of-0-or-1-remain-unchanged-with-new-information-intuitiv

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192242/is-e1-a-mathscrf-t-0-textor-1-rightarrow-e1-a-mathscrf

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180073/prove-disprove-probability-of-0-or-1-almost-surely-will-never-change-and-has-n

## Question(s):

Is it weird if those never come up in discussions, homeworks/assignments, textbooks or exams in...

1. in a regular maths undergrad programme?
2. in an applied maths undergrad programme?
3. in an applied maths grad programme?
4. in a quant undergrad programme?
5. in a quant grad programme?

I ask 4 and 5 in case some other areas of applied maths really don't make use of probability or statistics (reeeeeeaaaaaally though? *applied* maths?)

Comment: Given the question history you have supplied, it seems like you have a sort of obsession with various flavors of this question.  I have many such obsessions myself, and I often find that deep mathematics can stem from repeated contemplations on the same theme.  For instance "really getting to the bottom" of "area" has lead to geometric measure theory, etc.  However, I think you need to get outside of your own head enough to realize that others may not share this enthusiasm, and view it as more of a footnote.

Comment: @StevenGubkin ah i see ok thanks for replying. i didn't mean it like this programme should do this or that. i mean other people are accusing me like 'your programme should've had this or that' (actually they're saying that i should know this or that *anyway* given what my programme taught me, but let's just pretend it's the accusations i sound outside these round brackets). so my hope is that it's not weird at all so i can defeat them in the argument. did i understand you correctly, and if so, then do you understand me?

Comment: I would recommend letting such arguments die.  What purpose are they serving in supporting your wellbeing?  If they think this should be "obvious" and you do not, there is really no way to settle the disagreement.  It is a matter of opinion.  Whether something is "obvious" or not depends a lot on your own idiosyncratic understanding.  I am sure there are many things you would find "obvious" and not bother teaching explicitly which these people you are arguing with would struggle to explain.

Comment: @StevenGubkin ah thanks God bless you. btw are you the close voter?

Comment: *"$P(A|B)=1$ if and only if $P(A)=1$"*: Of course this is not taught in any maths programme (nor in any other programme) since it is false: The property $P(A|B) = 1$ does clearly not imply $P(A) = 1$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck 8.9k maths overflow huh? please give a counterexample https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186619/does-an-unconditional-probability-of-1-or-0-imply-a-conditional-probability-of-1

Comment: @BCLC: Take any $A$ with $0 < P(A) < 1$ and choose $B=A$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck ah thanks! in fact perhaps $B \subseteq A$ works? i guess. post as answer? apparently [probabilities of 0 or 1 do change](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192179/why-does-a-probability-of-0-or-1-remain-unchanged-with-new-information-intuitiv)? or maybe the idea is with filtrations. idk.

Comment: @BCLC Yes, I voted to close.

Comment: @StevenGubkin why don't you just give your comment as answer?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I didn't read the questions carefully to see the "if and only if" claim.  Indeed, this is seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of conditional probability.

Comment: @BCLC I don't give my comment as an answer because I do not think the question is appropriate for this site.  I want the question to be closed.

Comment: @StevenGubkin see the edit. so nassim nicholas taleb is wrong? or is right because the context is filtrations?

Comment: @BCLC I don't know who Nassim Nicholas Taleb is.  If they are saying that $P(A|B) = 1 \implies P(A) = 1$ then they are wrong.  You don't need an authority to certify this for you.  You can apply the definitions to an explicit counterexample as suggested by Jochen and confirm it without any doubt for yourself.

Comment: @StevenGubkin ah wait never mind i made a mistake. i misremembered the answer in the filtrations. i forgot about '[I don't think anything can be said about $E[1_A | \mathscr{F_s}]$ in general](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180073/prove-disprove-probability-of-0-or-1-almost-surely-will-never-change-and-has-n)' weirdly i remembered that it was also = 1. i edited post to remove the reverse implication. thanks!

Comment: @JochenGlueck ah wait never mind i made a mistake. i misremembered the answer in the filtrations. i forgot about '[I don't think anything can be said about $E[1_A | \mathscr{F_s}]$ in general](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180073/prove-disprove-probability-of-0-or-1-almost-surely-will-never-change-and-has-n)' weirdly i remembered that it was also = 1. i edited post to remove the reverse implication. thanks!

Comment: StevenGubkin and @JochenGlueck https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562216/wait-so-probabilities-of-0-or-1-can-change-pab-1-does-not-imply-pa-1-b

Comment: I'm not sure the close reason I chose is really appropriate, because I don't know what kind of edit could make this an answerable question. But it was the closest one I could find.

Answer (score 1):

It's not weird.  The institutions are busy teaching the bulk of their topics.  Busy with conveying (what is at the end commercially important) knowledge to imperfect recipients, with limited time.  Obsessing on this one particular question (or the earlier quadrilateral wording minutia obsession) would be weird (by which I mean a poor use of time/resources).

[If done by the institutions.  Whether weird for you is a separate question.]

Now that doesn't mean nothing is to be gained by your obsession.  Might be, might not.  But that's for your own edificaton.  Expecting the rest of the world to have your agenda is silly though.  People are different, institutions are different. Not everyone has your priorities and interests.  This is an important thing for you to know as a teacher.  To have some empathy, thoughtfulness of others.

Comment: thanks. i edited post. see 'edit' at the top please. does any part of your answer change?

Comment: I don't think so.  Whether the question is from you or from some people you talked to, the relevant issue is still coverage by institutions.  It's probably more general and interesting they way you had it before.  As for your personal situation, just learn it (or don't).  But don't expect previous courses to give you perfect coverage of everything.   Pick up what you need, when you need it.  And don't gyrate off of remarks from others.  People can always say you should have learned x or y (ancient Greek, naval chokepoints, etc.)  Even if they're right, just go learn it then!

Comment: 'But don't expect previous courses to give you perfect coverage of everything.' --> I don't. They did. Blame them not me. Don't shoot the messenger? :|